# how convert sequence of bits in ascii-string c#

Tags: c#, string, bit-manipulation

How do you convert a string of bits, such as

> 0100100001100101011011000110110001101111001000000101011101101111011100100110110001100100

to a string of ASCII characters like: "Hello World"?

Comment: Split it into octets (blocks of 8 bits)... Use Convert.ToByte(octet,2) on each, then use Encoding.Ascii.GetString(bytes)...

Comment: @SLaks hehehe nicely played :) I fear that till just add confusion, though

Answer (score 3):

You need to split them up into 8-character strings (bytes), call `Convert.ToByte(str, 2)`, put them in a `byte[]`, then call `Encoding.ASCII.GetString()`.

Comment: ToByte also allows fromBase usage - I.e. Convert.ToByte(octet,2)

Answer (score 1):

This code example should be clear:

```
String bits = "01001001000......0001100100"; // shortened here for demo purposes

byte[] bArr = new byte[bits.Length / 8];
for (int i = 0; i < bits.Length / 8; i++)
{
    String part = bits.Substring(i * 8, 8);
    bArr[i] += Convert.ToByte(part, 2);
}
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
Console.WriteLine(encoding.GetString(bArr));
```

Basically split the string in even parts,  store the resulting bytes in a byte array and then parse that in a specific encoding.

Answer (score 0):

```
public string GetBytesFromBinaryString(String binary)
{
    var list = new List<Byte>();

    for (int i = 0; i < binary.Length; i += 8)
    {
        String t = binary.Substring(i, 8);

        list.Add(Convert.ToByte(t, 2));
    }

    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(list.ToArray());
}
```

test:

```
var data = GetBytesFromBinaryString("0100100001100101011011000110110001101111001000000101011101101111011100100110110001100100");
```

output:

> "Hello World"

Answer (score 0):

Use this method

```
private byte[] GetAsByteArray(string BinaryString)
{
        return Enumerable.Range(0, BinaryString.Length / 8)
            .Select(i => Convert.ToByte(BinaryString.Substring(i * 8, 8), 2)).ToArray();
}
```

Then call it like

```
string binaryString = "0100100001100101011011000110110001101111001000000101011101101111011100100110110001100100";
string convertedText = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(GetAsByteArray(binaryString));
```